# 2 closed and disjoint subsets A, B in R^2 for which d(A,B) = 0

Tags: analysis

I am in search of 2 closed and disjoint subsets A, B in R^2 for which d(A,B) = 0 but can't finy any. Can someone help me?

Comment: The $x-$axis and the graph of $e^{-x}$?

Comment: Hint: The sets can't be compact. So they have to be unbounded...